# Jquery: Swap out HTML partials depending on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

With the current project I am working on (Using Bootstrap 3), the client has asked for major changes to the structure for mobile views.

I have used Zurb Foundations Interchange in the past: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html - Which is just awesome!

I am wondering if anyone has used a bootstrap alternative? Or if you have coded this before, what has been your approach? I'm a little lost in which direction to go on this one. Searching seems to yield little results. I will probably just do this programmatically, but like the idea of JS handling it.

Many thanks

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use JavaScript for that, as some browsers might not run JS. Send mobile devices to a different sub-domain, like m.mysite.com and change the layout based on that. Not sure which technology you use as the backend, but with an MVC/WebApi pattern, you should be able to re-use code quite easily in 2 different templates/layouts

Comment: witch browser is not running JS ? Maybe you can do the same thing that foundation might be doing. You use the attribute data-interchange. U retrieve the size of the window you define the small,medium,large interval. then you will be able to hide or show divs, you can even if you want load ajax ressources and replace the content of the original div.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that user3036342. I am thinking that I'll code it with PHP. I'm not really keen on the subdomian option. We have that currently and hope to remove it altogether. As a side note, there are only 1.2% of visitors that don't have JS enabled here in the UK and my guess is that they are probably bots of some sort. I appreciate your comments. I think its definitely the right way to go. Thanks again.  - Su4p _ I'll look at that too.I want to remove the elements from the dom completely to to avoid heavy pages.

Comment: you can upvote comments if you like them ;)

Comment: @T2theC did you get an answer for your question? You can use media queries to re-size items according to the size of the window. So you can have one website for all devices. No JS required. Pure css.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for a client and I used the built in Bootstrap `visible-xs`, `invisible-s` etc. to end up with several different versions of the page depending on the screen size. It was a bit fiddly but it didn't need any JavaScript and is easy to modify. It's an option at least and as you're already using Bootstrap everything you need is there.